# SQLAlchemy Postgresql database django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm

I am new to Django and have a question in regards to whether or not I have to re-enter data or can use existing data from a postgres database and apologize if this has been asked before.

I have a Postgres database in which I created with SQLAlchemy ORM.  I use this database for data analysis and want to create a web app for the data presentation.  I know that Django has its own modeling system and ORM, do I have to recreate the database from scratch since I created this with SQLAlchemy's ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inspectdb command from Django.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/legacy-databases/